# Download multiple files using Java in Xpages

Tags: java, servlets, xpages, lotus-domino, outputstream

I use this code in my xpage to download a file from a remote server. When the user click a download button from the xpage a new download.xsp page opens up and runs the code below.

```
#{javascript:
var exCon = facesContext.getExternalContext();
var response = exCon.getResponse();
var out = response.getOutputStream();

var zipfile = sessionScope.thezip;
var dname = zipfile.substring(zipfile.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);

dl.download(zipfile,dname);
sessionScope.thezip = null;

response.setContentType("application/zip, application/octet-stream");
response.addHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename="+dname);
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

facesContext.responseComplete();
out.close();
```

Download method (db.download(string,string)) is a Java method which is brought up to the xpage as a managed bean.

```
public void download(String filepath, String dname){
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try{
            Class.forName(jdbcClass);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

                String insSql = "INSERT INTO Cache(name,zip) SELECT '"+filepath+"',* FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'"+filepath+"', SINGLE_BLOB) AS import;";
                stm = con.prepareStatement(insSql);
                stm.executeUpdate();

            String sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Cache where name = ?;";
            stm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            stm.setString(1, filepath);
            rs = stm.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                InputStream zip = rs.getBinaryStream("zip");

                FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
                ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
                HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
                response.setContentType("application/zip, application/octet-stream");
                response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename="+dname);
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

                byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
                int c = 0;

                while ((c = zip.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
                    OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
                    o.write(buf, 0, c);
                    o.close();
                }
                zip.close();
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try{
                if(stm!=null){stm.close();}
                if(rs!=null){rs.close();}
                if(con!=null){con.close();}
            }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
        }

    }
```

This java code runs an sql query to get a zip file as bytes and store it in a table. Then it select this row and returns the bytes to the caller java method. This way i get the remote file because there is no webserver to provide a url.

My problem is how can i use the httpResponse outputStream so as to download 2 or 3 files? if i copy-paste the code i get only the first file. I i try not to close the outputStream i get an error that the stream is already in use.

Does anyone have any idea?

P.S: Above code is tested and works fine if i want to download 1 file only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet would likely be to combine the multiple files into another ZIP file dynamically using the `java.util.zip` classes. You could wrap the output stream with `ZipOutputStream` and then loop through your ResultSet rows, creating `ZipEntry` objects to distinguish each file within it.

Comment: This is exactly the approach we use for a couple specific use cases at my day job. A user generally knows what to do with a `zip`file (and that it likely contains more than one file), and a single network response is much easier to manage.

Comment: There is a great xSnippet on OpenNTF.org that shows how to create a zip of attachments.
https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=download-all-attachments-java